# Showing a view if a user is authenticated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble displaying a view when the user gets authenticated. Why wont a simple `ng-show="vm.isLoggedIn"` show the view when evaluated to `true`?

This is my `HTML`:

```
<div ng-show="vm.isLoggedIn">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

This is my Controller:

```
var MainCtrl = function(userAccount) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isLoggedIn = false;
    vm.userData = {
        userName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: ""
    };
    vm.login = function () {
        vm.userData.grant_type = "password";
        vm.userData.userName = vm.userData.email;

        userAccount.login.loginUser(vm.userData, function (data) {
            vm.isLoggedIn = true;
            vm.message = "";
            vm.password = "";
            vm.token = data.access_token;
        });
    }
}
```

This is the `userAccount` service I created.

```
var userAccount = function ($resource, appSettings) {
    return {
        registration: $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Account/Register", null,
            {
                "registerUser": { method: "POST" }
            }),
        login: $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/Token", null, 
            {
                "loginUser": {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                        var str = [];
                        for (var d in data) {
                            str.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
                        }
                        return str.join("&");
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

I don't think it has to do with `MainCtrl` or `userAccount`, but I included them for context.

Does `ng-show` prevent any `ng-view` from being shown? Even if `ng-show` evaluates to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you need to check.

1. In your html make sure you are using the "controller as" notation and your controller is named as vm:

   ng-controller="whateverCtrl as vm"

If you don't do this then vm.isLoggedIn won't evaluate correctly.

2. make sure your vm.login method is actually called so the flag is actually set to true. You should also set the flag in the controller initially to true to see that the flag actually has the effect you want. Once you see the thing, then turn it to false again and go on from there.

Even if this is probably not the issue I would actually code a flag check like this:

```
<div ng-show="vm.isLoggedIn === true">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've check both the problems. If I just leave `vm.isLoggedIn = true;` when the controller initializes, it will show up. I think the problem is getting `ng-show` to work when I update `vm.isLoggedIn` from a return on a `Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-include and vm.isLoggedIn can be url when it not false it will be included example:

```
<button ng-click="vm.isLoggedIn=user==authenticated?'put url hier':false">Include</button>
<div ng-include="vm.isLoggedIn"></div>
```